# Jogar Dados de Query Para DataGridView em C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, datatable

Olá pessoal estou enfrentando problemas com uma listagem.

Tenho um DataGridView carregando uma lista de produtos automaticamente e um combobox com os nomes das categorias, a ideia é que, quando selecionar uma categoria e clicar no botão listar, o DataGridView carregue somente os produtos daquela lista. Criei uma query, executei separadamente e ela funciona, o problema é, como passar o texto da combobox como parâmetro na hora de chamar a query?

deveria ser algo assim, mas dá erro

```
private void btListar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sCategoria = cbCategoriaProduto.Text;
    this.tabelaEstoqueTableAdapter.FillByCategoria(
          this.baseDadosInfoMasterDataSet.TabelaEstoque, sCategoria);
}
```

Consegui passar o parâmetro, eu estava fazendo errado, o correto era:

```
this.tabelaEstoqueTableAdapter.FillByCategoria(
     this.baseDadosInfoMasterDataSet.TabelaEstoque,
     "%" + cbCategoriaProduto.Text + "%");
```

Mas não mostra nenhum dado no datagridview :/

Comment: Não coloque a solução no corpo da pergunta, publique uma nova resposta com a solução.

Answer (score 2):

Desculpem-me por ter respondido na mesma pergunta.

Resolvi meu problema agora, depois de algumas horas tentando.

O jeito certo de chamar minha query foi:

```
this.tabelaEstoqueTableAdapter.FillByCategoria(
     this.baseDadosInfoMasterDataSet.TabelaEstoque,
     cbCategoriaProduto.Text);
```

De chamando entre `"%"` não dava certo, acredito que só funcione para selects com o `LIKE`. Agora deu certo.